# SQL Query, struggling to add another WHERE clause into statement correctly

Tags: sql, database

I have a statement that works fine. It pulls out all users status updates and displays them on the screen, according to my where clause etc.

I have since added a table into my database that says if a user if being blocked or not.
This database table is very simple.

It contains **id, user, blocking**

I have tried and tried but can't seem to incorporate this into my where clause by saying, if the person logged in **[user]** is blocking another **[blocking]** then don't show that update.

Here's the statement:

```
$result = mysql_query(
            "SELECT 

            tbl_status.id as statID, 
            tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
            tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
            tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
            tbl_status.date as statDATE,

            tbl_users.id as usrID, 
            tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
            tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
            tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

            tbl_photos.profile as photosPROFILE,
            tbl_photos.photo_link as photoLINK,
            tbl_photos.default_photo as photoDEFAULT,

            tbl_blocking.id as blockingID,
            tbl_blocking.user as blockingUSER,
            tbl_blocking.blocking as blockingBLOCKING,
            tbl_blocking.date as blockingDATE,
            tbl_blocking.active as blockingACTIVE

            FROM tbl_status 

            LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
            LEFT JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.profile = tbl_users.id 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking on tbl_blocking.blocking = tbl_users.id

            WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0' AND tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'
            ORDER BY tbl_status.date desc

            ");
```

Comment: where id not in (SELECT blocking from table) I think you overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

```
            WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0' 
               AND (tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1') 
               AND tbl_blocking.blocking is NULL
```